# Substract several values from one table to another value in a different table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

[image]

Hi I am trying to add a column named profit to table invoice.   I would like to obtain exactly the values that are in red. That values are the substraction of table invoice amountUsd column MINUS table carrierPayments amountUsd column, using column loadNumber as the ID.   It works if I have one carrierPayments per invoice using the following query.

```
SELECT i.*, i.amountUsd - cp.amountUsd AS PROFIT FROM invoice i INNER JOIN carriersPayments cp ON i.loadNumber = cp.loadNumber
```

But what if I have more than one carrierPayment with the same loadNumber as the ones with orange background.  Could it be possible to make the substraction of more than one carrierPayment to one invoice?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. Give tabular initialization code for input tables. Please format your code reasonably. PS What queries can you write that are relevant for getting the overall answer, even if you don't know how to further query them & put them together into your overall answer? See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: You say "make the substraction of more than one carrierPayment to one invoice"--So it seems that you want to subtract the SUM() of payments per load.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advices.  So finally I found what I was looking for.    `SELECT i.id, i.loadNumber, i.amountUsd - SUM(cp.amountUsd) AS PROFIT 
FROM invoice i INNER JOIN carriersPayments cp ON i.loadNumber = cp.loadNumber
GROUP BY i.id, i.loadNumber, i.amountUsd`

Comment: If that's not one of the posted answers, please consider posting it as an answer for others to find. You can accept it (after minimal wait) or another one as most helpful. Comments are ephemeral, posts are permanent. PS Column id is in your comment but not in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` and `group by`:

```
select i.*,
       (i.amountUSD - coalesce(p.amountUSD, 0)) as profit
from invoice i left join
     (select p.loadNumber, sum(p.amountUSD) as amountUSD
      from carrierPayments p
      group by p.loadNumber
     ) p
     on p.loadNumber = i.loadNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.*, i.amountUsd - sum(cp.amountUsd) AS PROFIT FROM invoice i INNER JOIN carriersPayments cp ON i.loadNumber = cp.loadNumber group by cp.loadNumber
```